# VBA Catia module organization

Tags: excel, vba, module, catia

I have a problem with organizing my CATIA macros and I can not find a suitable solution for it.

At the moment I have a large project that grew from smaller one in time. It is 10k lines big and it is written in one module. I would like to make it more readable and easier to modify / navigate by creating multiple commented modules. I have my "Main" module and GUI that would call other modules.
Problem is that CATIA makes every module I create accessible to use as a macro. I do not want that because I want user to make a shortcut for my Main module. 
I do not need to hide my code but it would be very hard to explain new user which macro he/she would need to use if the got 20 macros when importing one project.

I tried with "option private module" and even using password but I can not reduce number of available macros in that list. Only solution I can think of (and it is crazy) is to put every procedure/function in separate class.

[image: Example of tree structure in VBA and CATIA macro interface]

any experience or thought about this problem is welcome.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Exactly what is crazy about moving unrelated macros/procedures to their own class?

Comment: I have some checker for type of loaded document or correct names for generating files. I have never put that in separate classes, it is something I always used as sub or function...

Comment: You have `Sub` and `Function` procedures inside class modules too.

Comment: True. I never thought about creating classes for that uses. I will try that. Do you have any other idea how to organize modules? What are your personal preferences?

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing whatsoever that is *crazy* about refactoring your procedural code into class modules. In fact, **I would even go as far as calling it a best practice**.

Your macros can all look like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    With New MyAwesomeMacro
        .Execute
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub DoAnotherThing()
    With New SomeOtherMacro
        .Execute
    End With
End Sub

'...
```

So you have a `MyAwesomeMacro` class module with an `Execute` procedure (which can take arguments as needed):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Execute()
    'the old macro code here...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Mathieu, I have been testing this yesterday and today, and this works better than I hoped for. I have just one question for you. "MyAwesomeMacro" is created after "With New" command and it is freed with "End With"? What is the scope of its existence? If I would like to preserve some of its value I would need to pass it to some other variable/object?

Comment: Yes, exactly; you can have `Debug.Print` statements in the `Initialize` and `Terminate` handlers to confirm this. And you can declare as local variable of that type just like any `Worksheet` or `Collection` object, and pass them around too. I just didn't see a need for that in a "create-and-run" scenario.